# Set A is empty but the code "elif A=={}:" doesn't work

Tags: python, set

I'm writing code which checks whether the sum of subset could be S or not

```
Set={1,3,7}
sum=10

def subset_sum(A,S):
    if S==0: return True
    else if S<0: return False
    else if A=={}: return False
    else:      
        z=A.pop()
        C=subset_sum(A-{z},S-z)
        D=subset_sum(A-{z},S)
        return C or D
    
print(subset_sum(Set,sum))
```

when I debug it, A is empty before this code `else if A=={}: return False` but this code goes to `else: z=A.pop()`
and makes error

Can't understand the reason
Can you elaborate it?

Comment: `{}` is an empty *dictionary*.

Answer (score 0):

`{}` is an empty dictionary, not a set, instead check for empty set using `len()`:

```
Set={1,3,7}
sum=10

def subset_sum(A,S):
    if S==0: 
      return True
    elif S<0: 
      return False
    elif len(A)==0: 
      return False
    else:      
        z=A.pop()
        C=subset_sum(A-{z},S-z)
        D=subset_sum(A-{z},S)
        return C or D
```

Comment: Note that the proper way to test for an empty set/dict/list is not to check its length, but simply to use the fact that it is considered `False` in boolean context if empty, `True` otherwise. So it would be: `elif not A:`